# How can I use a jQuery event without binding it to the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to use the jQuery event `mouseleave` and notice you can bind it to an element such as doing the code..

```
$('#outer').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#log').append('<div>Handler for .mouseleave() called.</div>');
});
```

But I don't want to do it that way as then I would need to include that in the page header or JS file which would load for every page.

I would rather have it only used inline like you can do with other JavaScript events such as `onclick`, `onchange` etc.... can you do the same with this? If so, how?

Comment: `mouseleave` is not natively supported by all browsers (I believe only IE supports it).

Comment: why would you *want* to use inline events? If you absolutely had to you could just include a `<script></script>` right after the elements that need it rather than into every page.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm using jQuery.

Comment: @KevinB Well wouldn't you get the browser whining about there being no ID to attach the event to on all the pages that don't have that element?

Comment: Well yes, but you if you want to use inline event handlers, you can only use them for events that are natively supported.

Comment: @Brett Right, but onchange="myfunction()" isn't jQuery. onmouseleave"myfunction()" also isn't jQuery. And the browser will not "whine" or even care at all if the ID doesn't exist. It'l just skip right on by that code.

Comment: Include the js in the head of that one page - don't put it in an included js file.

Comment: @Brett: It seems you are worried that the code will throw an error if an element with such an ID does not exist. But it won't, jQuery simply returns an empty jQuery object and the `.on` method call won't have any effect. This is not `document.getElementById`.

Comment: `if ($('#outer').length == 1) //assign handler`

Comment: @FelixKling yes and no:, from the jQuery website: *"The mouseleave JavaScript event is proprietary to Internet Explorer. Because of the event's general utility, jQuery simulates this event so that it can be used regardless of browser. This event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer leaves the element. Any HTML element can receive this event."*

Comment: @René: Isn't that what I said (basically)?

Comment: @Archer We use a global header, didn't really want to introduce an extra header or additional code to check the page just for each binding event we need to add.

Comment: @RenéWolferink Right, but jQuery doesn't implement attribute events suchas onmouseleave, therefore only browsers that natively support it would possibly have such an attribute event. Such as Internet Explorer

Comment: @Brett place the code inline. `<div id="outer">...</div><script>$("#outer").mouseleave(...);</script>` Now the script will only be included when the outer div is there.

Comment: @Archer: You can do that, but you don't have to if it's only about avoiding binding the event handler.

Comment: @KevinB I really dislike using inline script tags line that; so think I'll just go with including it in the header each time.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, it's a habit that I got into that I know I don't need, but it's a placebo that some of us feel the need for ;)

Comment: @Brett, the jQuery method $() returns a jQuery wrapper around the set of selected elements. If no matching elements are found, it's simply an empty jQuery set, and further operations on it (like calling .mouseleave) have no effect. They won't throw errors.

Comment: I don't see how using attribute events are any better than using inline javascript like that, but I agree, i don't really like using either solution, it becomes difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Place your code in an inline `<script>` tag in the footer of the page you need it on (i.e. after the element you want to add the handler to).

Answer (score -1):

Add it on your site layout/template as a delegated event in a `<script>` block in your `<head>` section, ie:

```
<head><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('mouseleave', '#outer', function() { /** Your Log code **/ });
});
</script></head>
```

Comment: This will run every time the mouse leaves an element.  There is 0 need for delegation with this issue.

Comment: his goal was to not have to add his binding event on every page. delegation solves that problem and gives him the opportunity to keep his JS event handlers defined in a single spot. He could easily move that code to a JS file that gets included and can contain more objects/code he needs for his site as well.

Comment: I think you misunderstand both the question and delegation.  How is this any different than just adding a regular event handler on the page, attached to the 1 element?  I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Archer That depends on your definition of *"page"*. a page could be a single web page, or it can be a sub page that gets switched to and from via ajax the same way jQM does. But, even then, this probably isn't the best way to bind an event handler that will only ever affect one element at a time.

Comment: I fully understand delegation, I use it a lot where necessary. The question was pretty straightforward. Assuming he's using some kind of MVC pattern, he would have a site template/layout file, and each individual page would have its own view file. He didn't want to add code to each individual view file. I was just assuming that the `#outer` element was dynamic, or not included on every page. If that's not the case, then delegation is not required.